# how to open another page when form submitted at the same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, forms

i have a registration form in the popup. i want to when my form submitted the response as a Error print in my box in a div that opens under my form called "error-ajax". my problem is when the form submitted,the second page doesn't load in that div.

here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min_1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="main">
<!--div 1-->
<div class="comment1">
<p>YOUR COMMENT</p>
<div class="reply">
 reply
</div>
</div>
<!--End div 1-->

<div class="repetable">
<form class="formnazar-user">
<input type="textbox" />
</form>
</div>
<script>
$(function() {
 $(".repetable").hide();
 $(".reply").bind("click", function() {
 $(".repetable").hide();
 $(".repetable").slideDown("slow")
 $("#nazar").slideUp("slow");
});
 });
</script>


<!--div 2-->
<div class="comment1">
<p>YOUR COMMENT2</p>
<div class="reply">
reply
</div>
</div>
<!--End div 2-->

<div class="repetable">
<form class="formnazar-user">
<input type="textbox" />
</form>
</div>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of this, you have to submit your form as ajax request. Use data ans $("#form").serialze(), after receiving the response do the nessasary updates to your div element

```
$.post( "second-page.bc", $( "#form-1" ).serialize() )
    .done(function(data) {
        //update your div with data
    })
    .fail(function() {
        alert( "error" );
    });
```

Comment: i just want to load another page in a specific div

Comment: Load means you want to update user div with specific information which send by server right? In that case you don't have any other option apart from ajax ! Therefore in server side send necessary information to client, in client side you have to apply these changes in to the targeted DIV element.

Comment: but how? when i submit my form that open in a new page which is in my form action intead of open it in div.

Comment: Opps! That's why I suggested you to do a ajax request which will no reload the current page...

Answer (score -2):

you can user `window.open()` to redirect page to another page.
It has two parameter; first is where you want to redirect and second is the target. For example:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
window.open('success.php','_self'); 
</script>
```

Comment: `$(".error-ajax").load("second-page.bc");` for load other page to form.